# React native conditional spread prop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to spread props if `testId` exists. Can anyone please help?

I have tried these but allgenerate a compile error:

```
<Text style={forms.iosLink}
       ..{testId && TestIdHelper(testId)}>
   

 <Text style={forms.iosLink}
       {...(TestIdHelper(testId) && testId)}>
```

and

```
<Text style={forms.iosLink}
                  {testId ? { ...(TestIdHelper(testId)} : ''}>
```

I get the error, **Unexpected token, expected "..."**

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

when you spread entity, it need to be an object.

```
<Text style={forms.iosLink}
   {...(TestIdHelper(testId) ? { testId }) : {}}>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).